# MALLOC option in autotools eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, malloc, autotools

I'm struggling with autotools plugin in Eclipse and some C++ project I have downloaded.

My goal consists on cross-compilng for an arm processor, so the project is already configured to work with autotools, but when I try to crosscompile I have the following issue

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63,
                 from dtntracepath.cpp:17:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cstdlib:119:11: error: ‘::malloc’ has not been declared
```

I've checked out the configure output of my project noticing this

```
...
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... no
checking for memset... yes
...
```

I know how to fix it through linux terminal through adding the option

```
export ac_cv_func_malloc_0_nonnull=yes
```

but non through Eclipse or autotools pluging, since the settings of the project aren't available. May you enlighten me?

Kind regards,

Thanks in advance

PS: the parameters which I've set in autotools plugin are the following ones:

```
-Command: configure  CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32"  CC=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CC=c99
-All options :  --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-linux --target=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --with-sysroot=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/
```

EDITED:

I have tried ldav1s advice an using the following configure

```
configure CC=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++  CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32"
```

I get these errors

```
Command-line environment variables:
     LDFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32" CC="/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++"

sh -c /home/t/ibrdtn/ibrdtn-tools-0.8.0/configure      ++ --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --with-sysroot=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/ 
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: ++
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-strip... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
Invalid configuration `++': machine `++' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub ++ failed
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub ++ failed
checking build system type... 

Configuration failed with error
```

EDIT2
After reinstalling eclipse the ++ errors of first edition were gone, now if I use the following configuration

```
configure CC=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++ CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32"--host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-linux --target=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi
```

It was compiling properly, I have seen some arm/le outputs, but I have got this error
concerning to one of the libraries

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/t/ibrdtn/ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net'
  CXX    tcpclient.lo
  CXX    tcpserver.lo
  CXX    tcpstream.lo
  CXX    udpsocket.lo
  CXX    MulticastSocket.lo
  CXX    UnicastSocket.lo
  CXX    stopandwait.lo
  CXX    vsocket.lo
  CXX    vinterface.lo
  CXX    vaddress.lo
  CXX    LinkManager.lo
In file included from LinkManager.cpp:16:
../../ibrcommon/net/NetLinkManager.h:19:29: error: netlink/netlink.h: No such file or directory
../../ibrcommon/net/NetLinkManager.h:20:26: error: netlink/attr.h: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [LinkManager.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/t/ibrdtn/ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/t/ibrdtn/ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/t/ibrdtn/ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set up the C++ compiler (`CXX`) as part of your arguments to `configure`, as well as multiply defining the C compiler (`CC`).

You seem to be picking up the compiler for the build machine (the ones in `/usr/include`) instead of the one for the crosscompiler (the ones in `/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1`).

Comment: Thanks for replying,so in order to choose the proper crosscompilers, should I use something similar to this: `code configure  CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32"  CC=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++ ` ?

Comment: I did use that configure above and I was retreived that error, any suggestion of why it cannot understand the ++??

Comment: Why is `++` there? The arguments to `configure` don't look right.

Comment: I have no clue!! What I'm going to do is to reinstall eclipse....I'm  fed up of this weird behaviours.

Comment: Eclipse reinstalled, I tried the command again, getting the outputs of EDIT2 in main post. Thanks!